# getting logical error as Stack is empty , what is the error?

Tags: c, tree, stack

why i am getting stack is empty every time?
I am trying to make a expression tree from postfix here.
what's the logical error here?? plus we are not allowed to declare any variable globally. so, i had to pass the stackarray and node every time in each time function calling.
i am posting the full code done by me please have a look, i know its might be a simple error but as a beginner please show some kindness.

please help. TIA :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAXSIZE 10
struct ExpnTreeNode
{
    struct ExpnTreeNode *lchild;
    char data;
    struct ExpnTreeNode *rchild;
};
struct stackarray
{
    struct ExpnTreeNode *data[MAXSIZE];
    int top;
};
void push(struct ExpnTreeNode *newnode, struct stackarray *s);
struct ExpnTreeNode* pop( struct stackarray *s);
int check(char c);
void operand(struct ExpnTreeNode *newnode,char m, struct stackarray *s);
void operators(struct ExpnTreeNode *newnode,char m, struct stackarray *s);
void printex(struct ExpnTreeNode *node);


int main(void)
{
    struct ExpnTreeNode *p=NULL;
    struct stackarray s={{NULL},-1} ;

    int len;
    int x;
    int res;
    int i;
    char arr[30]={'\0'};
    printf("\n\tEnter a postfix expression:");
    scanf("%d",&arr);
    struct ExpnTreeNode *newnode=NULL;
    len=strlen(arr);
    for(i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++)
    {

        x=check(arr[i]);
        if(x==1)
        {
            operand(newnode,arr[i],&s);
        }
        else if(x==2)
        {
            operators(newnode,arr[i],&s);
        }

    }
    p=pop(&s);
    printex(p);
    return 0;

}

void push(struct ExpnTreeNode *newnode, struct stackarray *s)
{
    if(s->top==MAXSIZE-1)
    {
        printf("\n\tStack is Full");//Stack is Full
    }
    else
    {
        s->top=s->top+1;
        s->data[s->top]=newnode;
    }
}

struct ExpnTreeNode* pop( struct stackarray *s)
{

    if(s->top==-1)
    {
        printf("\n\tStack is Empty");
        return;
    }
        s->top=s->top-1;
        return(s->data[s->top]);
}

int check(char c)
{
    if(c=='*' || c=='/' || c=='+' || c=='-')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}


void operand(struct ExpnTreeNode *newnode,char m, struct stackarray *s)
{
    struct stack *fs=NULL;
    fs=s;
    newnode=(struct ExpnTreeNode *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct ExpnTreeNode));
    newnode->data=m;
    newnode->lchild=NULL;
    newnode->rchild=NULL;
    push(newnode,&fs);
}
void operators(struct ExpnTreeNode *newnode,char m, struct stackarray *s)
{
    newnode=(struct ExpnTreeNode *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct ExpnTreeNode));
    struct stack *fs=NULL;
    fs=s;
    newnode->data=m;
    newnode->rchild=pop(&fs);
    newnode->lchild=pop(&fs);
    push(newnode,&fs);
}
void printex(struct ExpnTreeNode *node)
{
    if(node!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\t%c",node->data);
        printex(node->lchild);
        printex(node->rchild);

    }
}
```